# How to convert entire DataRow to Key Value pair one by one

Tags: c#, wcf

I am looking for a solution in c# where I need to convert all DataRow to Key value pair.
Here is what my data is coming as of now,

```
{
"DynamicColumnsList": 
[   
{
"myRow":"Title|KeyQuestion|OfferingBanner|OfferingOverview|Image_x0020_Icon|KeyContacts|KeyContacts_x003a_ID|KeyInvestmentAreas|KeyIssuesMarketDrivers|KeyServices|TypicalBuyers|AdditionalColumn1|Base64Image|Base64Banner|FSOCrossSector|ID"     

},
{
"myRow":"BigBetsTestTier1|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|SomeData|14"
 }
 {
"myRow": "....."
 }
 {
 "myRow": "....."
 }
 {
 "myRow": "....." and so on...
 }
 ]
}
```

The First myRow has column names and below that Second myRow has the respective values of it and so on till 10 rows.

So is there any possible way to have data like below format,

```
{
"DynamicColumnsList": 
[ 
{
 "Title": "BigBetsTestTier1",
 "KeyQuestion": "SomeData",
 "OfferingBanner": "SomeData",
 "OfferingOverview": "SomeData",
 "Image_x0020_Icon": "SomeData",
 "KeyContacts": "SomeData",
 "KeyContacts_x003a_ID":"SomeData",
 "KeyInvestmentAreas":"SomeData",
 "KeyIssuesMarketDrivers":"SomeData",
 "KeyServices":"SomeData",
 "TypicalBuyers":"SomeData",
 "AdditionalColumn1":"SomeData",
 "Base64Image":"SomeData",
 "Base64Banner":"SomeData",
 "FSOCrossSector":"SomeData",
 "ID":"14"
 },
 {
 ...
 },
 {
  ... and so on 
 }
]
}
```

Comment: you can use Dictonary https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is that really a `DataRow`? Why you show it like a string that looks like json?

Comment: Hi Tim, I need to return after converting to JSON so I need to convert to KV pair. Above example shows what I have done from datatable but my output is not acceptable so I need below formatted output. Thanks

Comment: By using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DictionaryObj) its done!